# C# if statement not working

Tags: c#

My code works within a local network and I know it will not work outside of the local network as I am using Dns.GetHostEntry to resolve the IP address to hostname and thats fine...

But my if statement is not working, I am getting error "No Host Found" message when trying to resolve hostname from different subnet.

I thought my if statement would stop this error but its not working, can someone help please or tell me how to fix it, code below...

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    //public string IPaddr1 { get; private set; }

    string serviceDesk = "eg@mail.co.uk";
    string emailSubject = "MyPc";
    string IPaddr = "";
    string deviceName = "";


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getIP();
    }

    protected void getIP()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDER_FOR"] != null)
        {
            IPaddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDER_FOR"].ToString();
        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
        {
            IPaddr = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
            deviceName = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(IPaddr)).HostName;

        }
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.Length != 0)
        {


            deviceName = "Device name could be found";

        }


        Label1.Text = "IP Address: " + " " + IPaddr;
        Label2.Text = "PC Name: " + " " + deviceName;



    }


    private void EmailVerificationRequest(string recepientEmail, string subject)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
            {
                StringBuilder sbEmailBody = new StringBuilder();

                sbEmailBody.Append("IP address " + IPaddr + "<br/>");
                sbEmailBody.Append("Hostname " + " " + deviceName);

                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FromEmail"]);
                mailMessage.Subject = subject;
                mailMessage.Body = sbEmailBody.ToString();
                mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));

                SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

                smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
                smtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
                smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);

                System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
                NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(NetworkCred.UserName))
                {
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                }

                smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);

                try
                {
                    smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                }

                catch (SmtpException e)
                {
                }
            }
        }

        catch
        {
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EmailVerificationRequest(serviceDesk, emailSubject);
        Response.Redirect("~/message.aspx");
    }









}
```

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger?

Comment: Is the IP address your trying to fetch the `PTR` record from, as I guess, one of the private subnets by any chance? Or maybe one where no `PTR` exists? Or in other words, are you sure the used name server knows of that information. I suspect it just doesn't...

Comment: yep the DNS server does not know the record for the IP address, which is causing the error message, which is fine but I want my IF Statement to say, if we cant resolve IP address to hostname the message, device has could not be found...

Comment: Your if statements are very precise, maybe the return value is not what you think it is? Check the function signatures. And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: I would suggest you change the title of your question to a more relative question. This title is really generic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If the host name could not be found, the SocketException exception is returned with a value of 11001 (Windows Sockets error WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND). This exception can be returned if the DNS server does not respond. This exception can also be returned if the name is not an official host name or alias, or it cannot be found in the database(s) being queried.

Therefore, I suspect your code isn't getting as far as the third `if` condition because an exception is being thrown by the call to `GetHostEntry()`, which you're seeing as the 'error "No Host Found" message'.

The most straightforward way to deal with this is to use a `try...catch` block to catch the specific exception and handle it, something such as:

```
try
{
    deviceName = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse(IPaddr)).HostName;
}
catch (SocketException)
{
    deviceName = "Device name could be found";
}
```

This says that if a `SocketException` occurs during the call to `GetHostEntry()`, the code is to jump to the catch block, rather than the exception stopping your application.

Note that this assumes that any `SocketException` means that the IP address wasn't found, but it could mean that the DNS server wasn't contactable, or some other error.

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) has quite a lot on exception handling and how `try...catch` blocks work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Before you get a value from a dictionary, you must check if the dictionary contains the key you pass. You achieve this by calling "Contains" method.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables.Contains("HTTP_X_FORWARDER_FOR"))
{
    // Your Code...
}
```

If you retrieve the content of a dictionary directly and the key you are requesting doesn't exist in the dictionary pairs, the dictionary doesn't return null. Instead, it throws KeyNotFoundException.